# White space between image and border on image button

Tags: html, css

I am getting some white space between my image and the button border. I cant seem to get rid of it whatever i try.

```css
#rock_button {
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 265px;
  left: 19%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: hand;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: #3f441c;
  display: block;
  padding: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 10px 10px 5px black
}
```

```html
<button id="rock_button" class="slideRight" name="choice" value="rock">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XT41ZXk.jpg" alt="Rock">
    </button>
```

Any help would be great. Im using sinatra and ruby with my html if that makes a difference?

Comment: If someone's solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

`padding: none` should be `padding: 0;`

You also need to remove the default spacing around the `img` by using `display: block` ([further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)).

```css
#rock_button {
  outline: none;
  /*position: absolute;
  top: 265px;
  left: 19%;*/
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: hand;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: #3f441c;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow:  2px 10px 10px 5px black
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="rock_button" class="slideRight" name="choice" value="rock">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XT41ZXk.jpg" alt="Rock">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<button id="rock_button" class="slideRight" name="choice" value="rock">
  <!--<img src="http://i.imgur.com/XT41ZXk.jpg" alt="Rock">-->
</button>
```

Add the backgorund using css background image url tag also change padding:0 to reset padding space in browser default

css:

```
#rock_button {
width:50px;
height:50px;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 265px;
  left: 19%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: hand;
  text-align: center;
  border-color: #3f441c;
  display: block;
  padding: none;
  box-shadow:  2px 10px 10px 5px black
  background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/XT41ZXk.jpg');
}
```

Comment: add the height and width to the button

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/heok48q9/1/  check this it also has white space around button this is your code

Comment: The question is about _"white space between my image and the button border"_. Not space around the button.